# First page of PDF not visible in Skim when using "Two pages" PDF Display in OS X Sierra

Tags: pdf, macos, skim

I'm having an issue with Skim since upgrading to OS X Sierra, the first page of a PDF is not visible in "two pages" PDF display mode (the left-hand side should be the first page, but is instead grey):

[image]

I can make the first page visible if I switch to another display mode and then back to two pages, but as soon as I flip the page, the first page becomes invisible again!

This has only been an issue in Sierra, Skim was working fine in 10.11. Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Skim in my experience, just like Preview, always displays the first page by itself when selecting Skim > PDF > PDF Display > Two Pages _or_ Two Pages Continuous. I'm using version 1.4.22 (96) of Skim on macOS 10.12 and OS X 10.8.5 and the behavior is exactly the same in both versions of the OS and in Preview and Skim. As an example using a 2 page or a 332 page PDF, page 1 alway displays by itself when selecting Skim > PDF > PDF Display > Two Pages _or_ Two Pages Continuous and also the last page is displayed by itself when there is an even number of pages.

Comment: This is not what I am referring to here, the first page is *not* available at all, it is invisible in Skim. In what you are describing, the first page is centered in the window; here, the first page is simply invisible.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with the PDF's I have. Is there one you can point to online that I can download to test that you're having the issue with and see if it's any different then what I've described and is the normal behavior for me?  What version of Skim are your using?

Comment: @user3439894 make sure you don't have Skim in "book mode". That is where I am seeing the bug.